# cant store an HTML page when ncarchar(max) is capped at 4000 characters

Tags: c#, sql-server, nvarchar

To put it simple, how to increase the cap of nvarchar(MAX) to actually hold 280MB of text and not just 8000MB (correct me if I'm wrong)?

So, for my finals project I'm making a web-crawler for a client that wants its own customized search engine for their library website, but my problem arises when i try to store the infomation that the crawlers retrieve.

Specifically the problem I have is that even tho I set the column "HTML" to nvarchar(MAX), which should be able to hold 2GB of data, it wont save any infomation to it, in this case 280MB, cause it's too long.

I did try shortening the length of the text to be saved and when I made it sufficiently short enough it finally agreed to save the data, so from what I can understand it's capped.

**EDIT: Code examples as requested**

page container class:

```
public class Page
{
    public int ID = -1;
    public String URL;
    public String HeadLine;
    public List<String> Tags;
    public String Description;
    public String HTML;
    public DateTime lastUpdate;
}
```

Code snippet when crawler saves the page that it has retrieved:

```
//Save Page content to Database
Page page = new Page();
page.URL = url;
page.HeadLine = headline;
page.Tags = tags.Split(',').Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();
page.Description = description;
page.HTML = HTML;
page.lastUpdate = DateTime.Today;
new DBpage(Settings.instance.DBaddress,
Settings.instance.DBname).SavePage(page);
```

Method used for storing the data:

```
public void SavePage(Page page) {
    String SqlString = "";

    //Check is a page by the given URL already exists in the database and assign the SQL string acordingly
    Page foundPage = GetPage(page.URL); 
    if(foundPage == null) {
        SqlString = "INSERT INTO WebContent " +
                    "VALUES (@URL, @HeadLine, @Tags, @Description, @HTML, @LastUpdate)";
    }
    else {
        SqlString = "UPDATE WebContent " +
                    "SET URL = @URL, HeadLine = @HeadLine, Tags = @Tags, Description = @Description, HTML = @HTML, LastUpdate = @LastUpdate " +
                    //"SET URL = '" + page.URL + "', HeadLine = '" + page.HeadLine + "', Tags = '" + String.Join(",", page.Tags) + "', Description = '" + page.Description + "', HTML = '" + page.HTML.Replace("'", "''") + "', LastUpdate = " + page.lastUpdate + " " +
                    "WHERE ID = " + foundPage.ID;
    }

    //Assign all variables and execute the SQL
    try {
        using(DBaccess db = new DBaccess(dblocation, dbname)) {
            String html = page.HTML.Replace("'", "''"); //Replace all single quotes with double "single quotes" to escape the first single quote. 
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = db.GetSqlCommand(SqlString);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL", page.URL);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HeadLine", page.HeadLine);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tags", String.Join(",", page.Tags));
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", page.Description);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HTML", html);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdate", page.lastUpdate);
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch(SqlException e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

The unfortunate result that puzzles me:
[image: HTML is missing from this table]

Comment: Perhaps store a path to the html file on disk rather than the full data in the table?  SQL is not so great at huge amounts of data in a column like that.  If it's a project for an actual customer, consider using cloud storage or SAN.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the code you're using. I suspect that the issue is not the column but how you're trying to save data to it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I will try and fetch the code. Its currently on my work pc, please hold on.

Comment: For the record, when I said "maybe you should show us the code..." what I meant was "you should show us the code...", i.e. you should ALWAYS show us the code you're using.  A good question requires a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we're just guessing at what you did so we're just guessing at what you did wrong.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). I'd suggest taking *explicit* control over your parameter types and see if that remedies your situation.

Comment: I would like to state that I've already tried that. Tried to sqlCmd.add("@HTML, SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).value = html; but this still did the exact same

Comment: @SimonJensen, Maybe SSMS doesn't display the long value correctly. Try to run `SELECT LEN(HTML) FROM YourTable` to verify the length of the stored string. Overall, just step through the code in the debugger and verify that all variables have expected values. Also, double check the type of the `HTML` column in the database.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I think I am going to admit fault on my part. I did as you said and executed the SQL command you gave me in SSMS and despite what I expected, it indeed showed the length to be the 287857 characters. Did some quick and dirty testing to retrieve the data, and it was actually there ._. Now that I know that it was merely a visual thing I can finally move on with my project. I cannot thank all of you enough for your most valuable help!!

Comment: @SimonJensen, you are welcome. I moved my comment into the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`nvarchar(max)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) type does allow to store up to 2GB of data. For **n**varchar it means about 1 billion characters, because `N` types store text in 2-bytes per character unicode.

> **nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]**
>
> Variable-length Unicode string data. **n** defines the string length
>   and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. **max** indicates that the
>   maximum storage size is 2^30-1 characters. The maximum storage size in
>   bytes is 2 GB. The actual storage size, in bytes, is two times the
>   number of characters entered + 2 bytes.

Most likely your problem is somewhere in the procedure that tries to INSERT such large text. The first thing that comes to mind is some timeout. It will take a while to upload 280MB of data to the server, so examine the details of failure (look through the error messages and exceptions) to gather clues of what is going wrong.

---

Few things to check:

Double check the type of the `HTML` column in the database.

Maybe SSMS doesn't display the long value correctly. Try to run

```
SELECT LEN(HTML) FROM YourTable
```

to verify the length of the stored string.

Overall, just step through the code in the debugger and verify that all variables have expected values.

Comment: The thing is tho, I don't get any errors or exceptions, my sql fires and my url, headline, tags, lastupdate saves, while the HTML is just an empty field.

Comment: @SimonJensen, please edit the question and show your code. Ideally, you should make the minimal verifiable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Baronov, You are right, I'm still trying to get my work pc set up (messy desktop) and I'll be adding some of the code once I get it set up.